# Send raspberry pi IP on startup by email

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

I'm trying to make my RP accessible over shh on WIFI, but I don't have control over my router (I live in student dorms) and I cannot config a static IP, so I wrote a python script that will get the current IP and send it to my gmail account.
Then I added the script to `crontab`.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct
import fcntl

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', 'wlan0'[0:15])[20:24]))

msg = MIMEText(ip)

msg['Subject'] = 'RP IP'
msg['From'] = '****@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = '****@gmail.com'

try:
       mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

        #Login to SMTP server
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login('****@gmail.com', my_pass)

        mail.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], 'Subject: RP IP\n\nThe Current IP 
        mail.quit

        print "Success!"
except SMTPException:
        print "Error"
```

The problem is that the scripts returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Programming/python/send_ip_by_mail.py", line 11, in <module>
    ip = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', 'wlan0'[0:15])[20:24]))
IOError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

When I run the script myself it works fine, but on startup it does not.
What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: "At startup" is not precise enough - are you sure the interface is already up and got a dhcp address when you call your script?

Comment: Doesn't your raspi register a hostname with the router ?

Comment: @fvu well, I thought that might be the problem, but it used to work until I upgraded the raspbian version. Not it just throws that error.

Comment: @Marged I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you raspberry registers its hostname with the router you can access the raspberry using its name: raspberry.internal.net

Comment: @Marged, do you mean something like `avahi`?

Comment: @Algosub No, I am talking about normal DNS

Comment: @Marged Can you do that without access to the router? if so, how?

Comment: DHCP and DNS can work together. Determine your router and do some research or ask on serverfault because this has nothing to do with programming